# Finding a closed formula for a summation with two binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics

Given non-negative integers $m$ and $n$ with $m\leq n$, what is the following equal to?

$$
\sum_{k=0}^mC_m^kC_{n+k}^m={?}\tag{?}
$$
Here, 
$$
C_m^k=\frac{m!}{k!(m-k)!},
$$
so using standard notation for binomial coefficients the summation is
$$
\sum_{k = 0}^{m}{m \choose k}{n + k \choose m}.
$$
As a concrete example, for $(m,n)=(1,2)$, $(1,1)$ and $(2,2)$ one respectively gets following calculations: 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^1C_1^kC_{2+k}^1=2+3=5,\quad  \sum_{k=0}^1C_1^kC_{1+k}^1=1+2=3, \quad \sum_{k=0}^2C_2^kC_{3+k}^2=3+12+10=25.
$$
This problem is whether there is a closed formula for (?).

Comment: Is it possible that you have the superscripts and subscripts reversed? That is, $C_k^mC_m^{n+k}$? (so "m choose k" multiplied by "n+k choose m")

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe that there is a closed form for this sum, but we can get a [generating function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function) as follows:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{m}{k}\binom{n+k}{m}
&=\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{m}{k}\binom{n+k}{n-m+k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^m(-1)^{n-m+k}\binom{m}{m-k}\binom{-m-1}{n-m+k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^m(-1)^{n-k}\binom{m}{k}\binom{-m-1}{n-k}\\
\end{align}
$$
This is the coefficient of $x^n$ in $(1+x)^m(1-x)^{-m-1}$.

---

**Examples:**
$$
\begin{align}
m=1:&&(1+x)^1(1-x)^{-2}&=1+\color{#C00000}{3}x+\color{#C00000}{5}x^2+7x^3+9x^4+11x^5+\dots\\
m=2:&&(1+x)^2(1-x)^{-3}&=1+5x+13x^2+\color{#C00000}{25}x^3+41x^4+\dots
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I hope every answer provided respects the honest calculation made in the statement of the problem above.

Comment: @teh: Is there something that my answer is missing? As you can see in my examples, my answer matches your samples.

Comment: the problem is seeking a close formula, your answer just translated it to other equivalent problem, I thought.

Comment: This answer transforms one summation that isn't in table 137 of Concrete Mathematics (mentioned in my answer) into another one that isn't there either (it is like the Vandermonde identity but spoiled by alternating signs). The transformation is correct, but the result is not really easier to evaluate than the original.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: yes. As you mention in your answer, there is no closed form. However, generating functions are often useful in solving problems.

Answer (score 2):

Note that ${k\choose m}$ is zero unless $k=m$.  Then your sum simplifies to the single term ${m\choose n+m}$, which is again zero unless $m=n=0$, in which case it's 1.

Comment: $C_n^m:=\binom{n}{m}$

Comment: @Artem: That notation is only used in a few countries, and not typically in English-speaking ones.

Comment: @GlenO I know, that's why I provided the definition, which is used in these countries.

Comment: Indeed, it's $\displaystyle{\large\quad\sum_{k = 0}^{m}{m \choose k}{n + k \choose m}\quad}$. I never see anything like that notation. Then, $\displaystyle{\large m - n \leq k \leq m}$.

Comment: @vadim123 The notation $C_n^m$ is used in the former USSR and in most of the textbooks published there. The definition is, as I pointed in my first comment, is that $C_n^m=\frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}$. I _never_ saw in any textbook $C_n^m$ meaning $\binom{m}{n}$

Comment: @vadim123 Wikipedia lists the notation $C_n^k=\frac{k!}{n!(k-n)!}$ with the reference to the translation of Shilov, Linear Algebra. I checked and there is indeed notation like this in this book. However, when I checked the original Russian language edition, the notation is of course, along the line of the usual tradition: $C_n^k=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ Hence I suppose that this is either a mistake, or an attempt of the translator to make it look like usual English notation. Anyway, if you see anywhere this notation again, the chances are that my first comment is right.

Comment: The notation $C_n^p$ (for $\binom np$) has been taught traditionally in France (and even non mathematicians may understand "CNP" as a name for binomial coefficients), and is still in use a lot, even though the other notation is gaining some terrain recently. See for instance Théorème 3 in [this document](http://fr.scribd.com/doc/25774613/Combinatoire-et-denombrement) which I found by searching for "cnp combinatoire".

Answer (score 2):

There is no closed formula for this summation. In Concrete Mathematics there is a table (on page 169) of summations involving the products of two binomial coefficients with closed forms; all are variations of the Vandermonde identity. The easy way to remember which ones have closed forms, is that if the summation involves both upper or both lower indices (traversing them in opposite directions in case of upper indices), then without anything else a closed form exists, while if the summation involves mixed positions a closed form exists if (and only if) an alternating sign is present. In your expression there is summation over a lower and an upper index but no alternating sign; there is no closed formula.